# IOC containers: de-duplicating the configuration code

Tags: java, spring, oop, design-patterns, inversion-of-control

I am using spring framework for 2 different applications. Let's say both of the applications talk to one single MongoDB database. Following is how I configure MongoDB in both the applications:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("file:/etc/x/y/mongodb.properties")
public class MongoConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public UserCredentials mongoCredentials() {
        String mongoUserName = env.getProperty("mongodb.username");
        String mongoPassword = env.getProperty("mongodb.password");
        UserCredentials credentials = new UserCredentials(mongoUserName, mongoPassword);
        return credentials;
    }

    @Bean
    public MongoClient mongoClient() throws Exception {
        String mongoUrl = env.getProperty("mongodb.url");
        String mongoPort = env.getProperty("mongodb.port");
        MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient(mongoUrl, Integer.valueOf(mongoPort));
        return mongo;
    }

    @Bean(name="mongoTemplate")
    public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws Exception {
        String mongoDatabaseName = env.getProperty("mongodb.databasename");
        MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(mongoClient(), mongoDatabaseName, mongoCredentials());
        return mongoTemplate;
    }
```

Now, this piece of code is duplicated in two different application configurations. How do I avoid doing this configuration at two different places?

Comment: put it in a shared library and call it from both projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Treat it the same as a util class that you don't want to duplicate: move you config file to a separate project and make both your applications include that projects.

If you need to add additional project-specific configuration, Spring provides the @Import annotation that allows you to import configuration from separate classes, so you can create two project specific configuration classes that both import the generic configuration from the shared lib and supply their own individual beans and property sources, e.g.:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:/com/appspecific/app.properties")
@Import(com.genericlib.BaseConfig.class)
public class AppConfig {
 @Inject BaseConfig baseConfig;

 @Bean
 public MyBean myBean() {
     // reference the base config context
     return new MyBean(baseConfig.getSomething());
 }
}
```

Comment: That makes sense. I was considering this as a solution. Thank you so much for the answer! :) But here is another thing. What if I want to use different property source in different configurations but my rest of the class is the same?

Comment: You can use the @Import annotation for this. I have added more info to my answer to tackle that use case.

Answer (score 0):

Use Spring Boot, and optionally include the `@PropertySource` to add to the environment. It will collect all the MongoDB information and configure a client and template for you.

Comment: Nope. I have to use spring MVC and this configuration class. The problem statement is: how do I save myself from having 2 copies of this configuration class in my code base?

Comment: @riship89 You are aware that Spring Boot is used alongside, not as a replacement for, Spring MVC, and that it simply includes almost an exact duplicate of this class with the parameterization you want?